# How do i get the recent company updates from linkedin using OAuth2

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am creating a html page were am trying to get the recent updates about the company from following REST call : 
`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1441/updates?oauth2_access_token={access_token}`

I am getting reply as invalid access token , I have created a new application on linkedin developer network obtained the accesstoken and i am supplying the same access token in the REST call to get company updates .

Can i please know how do i get recent company updates from linkedin using OAuth and bind the output data to some placeholder on html page.

Comment: Do you got any solution?? Plz Share solution..with Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'OAuth User Token' of the applicaiton in the LinkedIn Developer site is NOT the oauth2token. To get the oauth2token you have to authenticate (as a user) following this guide: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Good luck! :)